# Understanding the Composer commands for upgrading Drupal 9 to Drupal 10

Tags: drupal

I have installed Drupal 9 with `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project`. I wish to upgrade to Drupal 10.

[Upgrading a Composer-based site / Overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-from-drupal-9-to-drupal-10-0/overview) doesn't explain what to do, but I have found [Upgrading a Composer-based site](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-a-composer-based-site) which does.

If I understand correctly, for typical (non-dev) versions, such as I have (according to `recommended-project`), this is the process:

```bash
cd example.com
composer update
chmod 777 web/sites/default
chmod 666 web/sites/default/*settings.php
chmod 666 web/sites/default/*services.yml
composer require 'drupal/core-recommended:^10' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^10' 'drupal/core-project-message:^10' --update-with-dependencies --no-update
composer update
drush updatedb
chmod 755 web/sites/default
chmod 644 web/sites/default/*settings.php
chmod 644 web/sites/default/*services.yml
```

I understand most code but not the following command

```bash
composer require 'drupal/core-recommended:^10' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^10' 'drupal/core-project-message:^10' --update-with-dependencies --no-update
composer update
```

What does this command do? It requires the recommended version of Drupal 10, so far so good, but what are the two other parts, what is a "scaffold" and "message" in this context and are these necessary?
 When installing Drupal, I don't recall ever coming across these terms.

---

I first published [a similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/314214/upgrading-from-9-to-10) in Drupal Answers Stack Exchange but was badly received there.
In the comment section, `user:zsd` wrote:

> - [github.com/drupal/core-project-message](https://%22github.com/drupal/core-project-message%20This%20Composer%20plugin%20displays%20a%20configurable%20message%20after%20Composer%20installation%20processes%20have%20finished.%20github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold%20This%20project%20provides%20a%20composer%20plugin%20for%20placing%20scaffold%20files%20(like%20index.php,%20update.php,%20%E2%80%A6)%20from%20the%20drupal/core%20project%20into%20their%20desired%20location%20inside%20the%20web%20root.%20Only%20individual%20files%20may%20be%20scaffolded%20with%20this%20plugin.%22) This Composer plugin displays a configurable message after Composer installation processes have finished.
> - [github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold](https://github.com/drupal/core-composer-scaffold) This project provides a composer plugin for placing scaffold files (like index.php, update.php, …) from the drupal/core project into their desired location inside the web root. Only individual files may be scaffolded with this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way composer works, `drupal/core-recommended` is everything you see in the `web/core` directory.

However, for Drupal to work, you need a number of files that are in your `web` directory ( things like `robots.txt`, `.htaccess`, `index.php` etc. ).
Those are downloaded by the `scaffold` project ( you can even customize via `composer.json` if you want to omit some, which is extremely helpful for stuff that are not relevant to the specific installation. These files are meant to be in source-control as well ( looking at `.htaccess` and `robots.txt` mostly), which would defeat the purpose of having them in core.

```
        [..]
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "file-mapping": {
                "[web-root]/.ht.router.php": false,
                "[web-root]/example.gitignore": false,
                "[web-root]/INSTALL.txt": false,
                "[web-root]/README.txt": false,
                "[web-root]/web.config": false,
                "[web-root]/README.md": false,
                "[web-root]/sites/README.txt": false,
                "[web-root]/modules/README.txt": false,
                "[web-root]/themes/README.txt": false,
                "[web-root]/sites/example.sites.php": false,
                "[web-root]/sites/example.settings.local.php": false,
                "[web-root]/sites/default/default.services.yml": false,
                "[web-root]/sites/default/default.settings.php": false
            },
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
```

The `message` project on the other hand is quite less needed - it simply displays the banners for sponsoring / support after a composer operation in your console. Does not install anything, but is required by some projects that are in search of sponsorship. Can also be customized through `composer.json` to not emit anything:

```
       [..]
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            ]
        }
```